# how to put computed value in RESX at build time C#

Tags: c#

I have a situation where in I have a string that should contain today's date in it.. 
the issue is that I need to put that string including today's date in the .resx file. 
is there any way to do that?
e.g. 
lets say about copyright string 
it should be copyright-2012-abc is today's date is of year 2012 
&it should be copyright-2013-abc is today's date is of year 2013

EDIT: 
I m going to use the resource file for this copyright thing only.
it will be static for all other things just that year value will be changing with every passing year just like in the example.

Comment: Why don't you use just a placeholder? In the resx-file you can have something like "Actual year {year}" And in you c#-code, where you access the resx-file you can parse the {..}

Comment: Title of your question is "get today date from RESX" (impossible), but body is "how to put computed value in RESX at build time"  - please try to make title and body agree on your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to add "current environment" values to RESX (or any other C# related files).

But you can relatively easy create pre-build rule that will call your custom script/tool that will modify your RESX file to your liking.

One option it to create tool that will genreate a file that later included in the RESX file. This way you avoid modification of RESX file itself (which could be problematic if RESX is under source control). Depending on your need simple `date /t > ..\..\out.txt` with out.txt include in RESX maybe enough.

Steps to include a file created at build time into RESX:

- Add TextFile1.txt to your project
- Drop that file on {resourceFileName}.RESX (in design mode)
- Check if {resourceFileName}.Designer.cs is updated with new property to access content of the new resource
- In Solution explorer chose properties of your project and open "Build Events" tab
- Add "date /t > ....\TextFile1.txt" to pre-build steps (will dump current date into "TextFile1.txt"
- Build and use new resource variable i.e. `Console.WriteLine(Resource1.TextFile1)`

RESX sample content:

```
  <data name="TextFile1" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>textfile1.txt;System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;utf-8</value>
  </data>
```

Answer (score 0):

resx is for storing static resource. Though there could be hack to change resx at run time, or during development time through some sort of scripting, however, both introduce too much complexity for little feature.

If you could clarify the use cases of such copyright string, readers might be able to provide more concrete suggestion. Say, do you use the string only for displaying in an About box? or assembly attribute?