# Any way to create a compile time timebomb to guard test-code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

***Problem Description:***

As a **single developer** I've stumbled across this several times:
Sometimes on a project instead of choosing a cleaner approach it makes sense for efficiency reasons to just add some quick and dirty test-code within production code.

#### While it may sound like a dirty solution, please keep in mind, that I'm only talking about test-code that should be thrown away anyway, when I just want to quickly check something.

To be 100% sure to not forget to take this code out again I'd like to guard it by a **compile time timebomb:**
What I mean is some piece of code, preprocessor code or anything basically that allows for compilation for a certain timespan, like half an hour for instance and then automatically results in a compiler error after the time (half an hour) is over. A compiler error would be great because it could directly mark the place of the test-code. (I could have it as the first line(s) within such a throwaway region for instance)

So anything like "throw an error if system time is bigger than this specific DateTime" would be great.

I looked into the preprocessor (not too familiar with it) but the directives #if and #error didn't seem like an option since #if expects a symbol instead of an expression.

***Question:***

**Is such a timebomb possible? Any idea on how to do that?

Or any idea on how to get the efficiency of quick and dirty test-code and be absolutely sure that taking it out again can't be forgotten?**
(A run time error would be easy but if a compile time error isn't possible I would need something of a similar quality to it.)

Comment: You want to write code with a life span of 30 minutes?

Comment: Yes for instance for figuring out an intricate bug it made sense to add sleep time to see if the problem gets worse or not and that's sth. that should not be in production code ever but doesn't really warrant a lot of effort like a new development branch.
Keep in mind single developer...

Comment: Write such code in a throwaway class, outside of source control.

Comment: Duplicating the whole class to add one line of code is obviously way less efficient, than if the other option was possible.

Comment: Side note: Being single developer does not mean you can't review your code before checking in... just look at diff and revert whatever test code you've wrote - no need for branching...

Comment: I personally use `//DEBUG: Explanation` comments.  Resharper has a tool that shows all locations where this is found, but you can also just do a simple Find In Files across the solution when you want to check whether these have all been cleaned up.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that is what I'm doing right now the whole point is to avoid opportunities for human errors and limit them to the adding of the test-code, instead of even having the opportunity to make a mistake at two different points in time. Somewhat similar to "don't make me think", like when I can get the *same* result with less brain activity I see it as an advantage

Answer (score 1):

I personally think, that timebombing is the wrong approach. Use build targets to distinguish different purpose of code usage.

```
    // Constructor call will only be allowed for target DEBUG 
    public class Protect : IDisposable
    {
#if DEBUG
        [Obsolete("error", false)]
#else
        [Obsolete("error", true)]
#endif
        public Protect()
        {

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
        using (new Protect())
        {
            // do some testcode
            // will only compile in DEBUG mode
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to generate file that has "current time" variable at build time and than simply add check that code should stop working after particular time.

Possible approach to generate file at build time - [how to put computed value in RESX at build time C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128244/how-to-put-computed-value-in-resx-at-build-time-c-sharp)